# Apache POI HSSF. Get total pages count

Tags: java, apache-poi

I work with POI and want to make printable report. So all fine, but I need to get total pages count (page in A4 format) of dynamically generated `.xls`. When  use `HeaderFooter.numPages()` I get instead of total pages count this symbols:  `&N`

Comment: That information isn't stored in the file format, so Apache POI likely won't be able to help, because the information isn't there to give you! Have you thought about using something like OpenOffice to generate a PDF of it, and then counting the pages in the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gagravarr is correct. Since the number of pages that will be printed is stored, there's not really a way to access it from the Apache POI. I would suggest switching the excel file to a PDF and counting it that way as was suggested.